# Why can't the product of an acid reacting with water react with water itself and produce OH-?

Tags: acid-base, equilibrium

Why can't the product of an acid reacting with water react with water and produce $\ce{OH-}$?
Take the reaction below as an example:

$$\ce{H2CO3(aq) + H2O(l) <=> HCO3-(aq) + H3O+(aq)}$$
$$\ce{HCO3-(aq) + H2O(l) <=> CO3^2-(aq) + H3O+(aq)}$$

Why can't the $\ce{CO3^2-}$ react with water (not $\ce{H3O+}$) and produce $\ce{OH-}$ ions? If it can then why is the solution acidic and not basic?

PS. I am a high school student and would really appreciate a straightforward answer.

Comment: It can and does. They all sit together in a nice equilibrium.

Comment: The following hydrolysis reaction is a well known equilibrium : $\ce{CO3^{2-} + H2O <=> HCO3^- + OH-}$ But $\ce{CO3^{2-}}$ is not an acid. It is a base.

Comment: Convenient reference for text/formula formatting:
 [Notation basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation)  /  [Formatting of math/chem expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here)  /  
[upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized)  // [For more:  Math SE MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  // Not to be applied in CH SE titles.

Comment: @Maurice I see. But if this reaction also happens in a container with water and H2CO3, why is the solution and acid and not a base?

Comment: Imagine CO2 solution with anions OH-, HCO3- and CO3^2-. As the only present cation is H3O+ and there is requirement of electroneutrality, there is more H3O+ than OH- and the solution must be then acidic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It definitely does. Let's simplify it to a monoprotic acid (like acetic acid, $\ce{CH3COOH}$), which I'll just represent as $\ce{HA}$ for simplicity. In a solution of the acid, you will have *all* of the following species floating around: $\ce{HA}$, $\ce{A-}$, $\ce{H2O}$, $\ce{H3O+}$, $\ce{OH-}$. *Every* conceivable reaction between these species will happen, such as:

$$\begin{align}
\ce{HA + H2O &<=> A- + H3O+} \tag{1} \\
\ce{A- + H2O &<=> HA + OH-} \tag{2} \\
\ce{2 H2O &<=> H3O+ + OH-} \tag{3}
\end{align}$$

To obtain a completely accurate value for the pH, and the equilibrium position, it is necessary to take all of these equations into account.*

But often we can get away with less work, and only bother with the first. Why? One qualitative way of looking at it is: when we add a weak acid $\ce{HA}$ to water, we know that *very little of it will dissociate anyway*; this is kind of by definition. So, there isn't much $\ce{A-}$ in the system anyway; and the second reaction can pretty much be ignored.

That's not to say that there is *no* $\ce{OH-}$ in the system. There *is* still $\ce{OH-}$ floating around. For example, in a pH 5 solution (i.e. $[\ce{H+}] = \pu{10^{-5} M}$), we have that $[\ce{OH-}] = \pu{10^{-9} M}$.* It's still there, it's just that there's very little of it.

A more formal explanation would involve solving it properly and verifying that the *true* solution is very close to the *approximate* solution obtained by ignoring eqns. (2) and (3).

On the other hand, if $\ce{HA}$ is a strong acid (like $\ce{HCl}$), then the reverse reaction $\ce{Cl- + H2O -> HCl + OH-}$ is completely negligible because $\ce{Cl-}$ is a pitifully weak base. (Strong acids have very weak conjugate bases.)

---

* In fact, these equations are not independent; note that (1) + (2) = (3), so there are only two 'pieces of information' to be obtained from these reactions, one corresponding to $K_\mathrm{a}$ and one corresponding to $K_\mathrm{w}$. But that's a story for another day.

Comment: Wow, this is the best explanation I have ever received! Although I am still wondering if the acid is so weak that we can ignore the second reaction (due to the small amount of A-) how can the H3O+ make a difference? (considering the fact that the amount of A- and H3O+ is the same?)

Comment: In pure water, which is pH 7, there's only $\pu{10^{-7} M}$ of $\ce{H3O+}$. You really don't need a lot of extra $\ce{H3O+}$ to turn that into pH 4 or 5, so just the tiny bit that dissociates from the weak acid is enough.

Comment: if this is the case, then how can we ignore the reaction that A- will have with water and the small amount of OH- that gets produced?

Comment: @AuthenticMelody [H3O+]=[OH-]+[HCO3-] + 2[CO3^2-] -> [H3O+] >[OH-] -> pH <7.

Comment: @AuthenticMelody Because basicity (as judged by pH > 7) isn't caused by A-; it's caused by OH-. Reaction 1 starts from quite a lot of HA and generates a tiny bit of H3O+ and A-. Reaction 2 starts from a tiny bit of A-, and generates a vanishingly small amount of OH-. Of course, implicit in this is the assumption that HA is a weak acid and A- is a weak base. This *is* true, though: consider acetic acid, pKa = 4.76; that's a weak acid. The conjugate base, acetate, has a pKb of 14 - 4.76 = 9.24; that's *also* a weak base. So, reaction 2 pretty much just doesn't happen.

Answer (score 2):

I really like this question because it digs at wanting to understand what's going on beneath the equations you've been given to know *why* that equation works.

Orthocresl answered it really well, but I might be able to get a little more to what pH and pOH are and give a little more understanding to what's meant by acidic and basic, and what equilibrium is. I feel like that might be as much your question as whether or not H2O can react with CO3 2- (apologies, first time answering a question here, and not sure how to format this correctly).

tl;dr version up front:

Pure water has an equal amount of H+ and OH-, both of them exist in water. We consider this neutral, neither acidic or basic. Anything that moves the concentration to favor more H+ is considered an (Arrhenius) acid, anything that moves the concentration to favor more OH- is considered a base. Even so, there will still be both H+ and OH- in the solution. Individual water molecules will continue to accept protons (H3O+, usually shown as H+) and donate protons (OH-), but there will be more water molecules accepting a proton to form H3O+ than donating them to form OH- at lower pH.

non tl;dr version:

Very, very few chemical reactions are truly one way/irreversible unless the products leave the system entirely. Almost all will be occurring in both directions at the same time. But, one will be occurring more/faster. Let's say reaction A occurs twice as fast as the reverse reaction B (A: a + b -> c; B: c -> a + b). Since A occurs twice as fast a B, then there will be more products, c, than reactants, a and b. However, c will still be producing a and b. Eventually you'll get enough c that the reaction will reach a point that it will *look* like the reaction stopped. If reaction A occurs twice as fast as reaction B, this will be when there's twice as much products as reactants.

Basically, if a + b produce c twice per minute, and c produces a + b once per minute, you'll eventually get twice as much c as you have a and b, and the reaction will look like it stopped from a macro point of view, but will continue to occur in your solution.

Take what I said there from a conceptual view. It's useless for practical purposes. If you want to know the math, this video explains it really well (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2PM1yc_z4Bk&list=PL2ub1_oKCn7qmUZ80MJDPaRTdgJm8ZenX).

I don't see a good way to not discuss different definitions of acids even though I feel it's a little beyond this question. Arrhenius acid is anything that lowers the pH of pure water (base is the opposite). But that's not a good definition. A much better one is the Bronsted definition, anything that donates a proton acts as an acid, and anything that accepts a proton acts as a base (there's a 3rd definition, but it's difficult to understand at first). In this case, your carbonic acid is acting as an acid when it donates a proton to water to form H3O+, and water acts as a base. However, the reverse happens as well. H3O+ will donate a proton to HCO3-. In which case H3O+ is acting as an acid. H2O can also act as a Bronsted acid and donate a proton to form OH-. So yes, CO3 2- can and does act as a base and accept a proton from H2O, and you get OH- floating around.

In *any* aqueous solution, you'll end up with both H3O+ and OH-. This is usually measured with pH. pH is actually the result of this equation pH = -log(10)([H+]). That equation means that pH is the negative base 10 logarithm of the concentration of protons (hydronium ions) in the solution. However, because we know there's an equilibrium between [H+] and [OH-], we can actually measure this in terms of the concentration of OH- ions instead, pOH. pOH is remarkably, the negative logarithm of the concentration of hydroxide ions, pOH = -log(10)([OH-]).

So let's say you have a pH of 5, a slightly acidic solution. You'll have a pOH of 9. The pOH measures in the opposite direction, pOH below 7 is basic, above 7 is acidic. These two measure will equal 14. A pH of 1 will correspond to a pOH of 13. So even at a very high acidity of pH 1, you will still have H2O acting as an acid and donating protons to form OH-. It will just be happening very slowly, and so there won't be many of them.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer. It really helped me gain a better understanding of the topic.